# Collapsing the medial axis of a polytope  

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, convex-polytopes, hyperbolic-geometry

**Let X be a convex polyhedron in hyperbolic 3-space.**

**Let M be the medial axis of X.**

**Question:  Is M collapsible?**

It is easy to see that M is contractable.
In the case of Euclidian 3-space, instead of hyperbolic 3-space, I think I have an elementary proof for the analogues statement.
In hyperbolic space, I guess that the statement still holds, but I do not have a proof.

I would appreciate comments and references for the above question.

**Definitions for the above question**

The MEDIAL AIXS of X :  consider a maximal round ball  inscribed in X (maximal with respect to set inclusion), which at least has two points of tangency (on $\partial X$).  Take the union of the centers of all such maximal balls inscribed in X.  Then, this union is called the medial axis of X, and it is a polygonal complex, to be precise, after adding the 1-skeleton of  the boundary of X.

M is COLLAPSIBLE: There is  a strong deformation retract of M to a point that is a composition of certain simplicial homotopies, each of which reduces a single cell.

Comment: Your Euclidean proof should work for the Klein/Beltrami disk model, right?